# Updating Android App without losing local data

Tags: flutter, storage, updates

I have written an app in flutter and I use a local storage(JSON file) to save data. I want to know how can I update app later without losing local user data.

Comment: What do you mean by "update app"? You won't lose any locally stored data unless the user manually deletes the app data in their device settings in which there's nothing you can do unless you store data in an online database such as Firebase.

Comment: By updating app I mean downloading new version form play store or app store

Comment: Well usually if you update the app through app/play store you do not lose data stored on the device. you lose data by uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Comment: @MozartAlKhateeb However now, Google is asking users whether they want to save their app data when they uninstall.

Comment: @BenjaminS. So would this be a problem in the context of this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Overview

As @MozartAlKhateeb said, you **don't** need to do anything on your end when the user updates the app as the **data is kept**. The only time they could **lose** their data is if they **uninstall the app**, or they **clear the app data manually**.

### When the app updates

**If** the update breaks the way you store data (say you changed the key that stores information), you would have to have a way to convert the data between updates. **However**, if you don't plan on changing the way you store data locally, you **shouldn't have to worry about this**.